# WebRequest and Node.js - error handling

Tags: c#, .net, node.js

What would be the correct way of handling errors in communication between a C# client app and Node.js server? My solution was to send status code 400 or 500 and error message in the response body, but WebRequest seems to not receive the body message when status code implies an error. I need to read this error message to show for the user the correct info about the error.

I guess typically server would throw WebRequestException which could pass the error message, however I have no idea how to throw such error from the Node.js app.

I cannot change the status code to 200 and read error from the body because previous versions of the app would not handle it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. In the client, in the catch block, when WebRequestException is thrown because of the error status code, you can still begin receiving the response (the response is in this exception).

My bad. :)